# Creating Android WebView with JavaScript Items

Tags: java, android, performance, webview, android-webview

I'm creating an application for Android Tablets.
The WebView and the application works great but when I want to interact with the JavaScript (like moving some Items), the application become really slow and laggy.
I tried to enable the hardware acceleration but it seem not to work better. I tried also to disable the multitouch.
The problem is if I use the default Browser on Android it works great and it is really smooth but when I use the WebView (Chromium) it become laggy.

Does someone already had this problem ?

Here is the code I use for the WebView Settings

```
WebSettings webViewSetting = webView.getSettings();
webViewSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webViewSetting.setUseWideViewPort(true);
webViewSetting.setSupportZoom(false);
webViewSetting.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
webViewSetting.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4; Nexus 5 Build/BuildID) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36");
```

Comment: Are you hitting this bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62641

Comment: yes I think it is the same problem.